# Multiple covering of a specific map $w:D^2\rightarrow S^2$

Tags: complex-analysis, covering-spaces

Suppose I have a map $w: D^2\rightarrow S^2$ such that $w(\partial D^2)\subset L$, where $L$ is the equator. Is there a way of knowing what are the branched coverings of this map ? By this I mean a map $f:D^2\rightarrow D^2$ such that $f$ is a covering map except on a finite set of points , and the existence of a map $w':D^2\rightarrow S^2$ such that $w'\circ f=w$.

I am interest in what happens in the boundary of the disk , i.e., if it has to send to send $\partial D^2$ to $\partial D^2$ by a map of the form $z^n$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by "branched covering of this map" again? You seem to be talking about a cover of $w$, but there's no $w$ in the definition you gave...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, $w$ is specified. But there's no mention of $w$ **in the definition of** "branched cover over $w$".